# Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc. What could be causing it?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Same code that I was working on last night, has thrown up a whole new error. One that I've never encountered before, and I am at the point of considering throwing things at my PC. But, everyone here was very helpful last night, so I thought I'd see if anyone had any ideas on this new problem.

Something is causing "Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc" and I think it's within the first line of the main.cpp, but as that is just creating the player as a Hero (child of creature) class. I can't see why it can't do it.

I know it's probably something stupid, that I've done badly ... but any help would be appreciated!

```
//main.cpp

#include "Creature.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hero player(1);
    Monster baddie;

    player.setX(1);
    player.setY(1);

    baddie.setX(20);
    baddie.setY(20);

    player.Display();
    baddie.Display();

    baddie.chase(player);
    player.Display();
    baddie.Display();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}


===================================

//Creature.h

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Creature
{
protected:
    int m_xpos;
    int m_ypos;
    string m_name;

public:
    Creature(string name, int xpos, int ypos);
    void Display(void);
    void left(void);
    void right(void);
    void up (void);
    void down(void);
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    int getX(void);
    int getY(void);
};


===================================

//monster.h

#pragma once
#include "Creature.h"

class Monster : public Creature
{
public:
    Monster();
    void chase(class Hero);
    bool eaten(class Hero);
};

===================================

//Hero.h

#pragma once
#include "Creature.h"

class Hero : public Creature
{
private:
    int m_lives;
    int m_score;

public:
    Hero(int lives);
    void Display(void);
    void setScore(void);
};

===================================

//creature.cpp

#include "Creature.h"

Creature::Creature(string name, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    m_xpos = xpos;
    m_ypos = ypos;
    m_name = name;
}

void Creature::Display(void)
{
    cout << m_name << endl;
    cout << m_xpos << endl;
    cout << m_ypos << endl;
}

void Creature::left(void)
{
    m_xpos = m_xpos+1;
}

void Creature::right(void)
{
    m_xpos = m_xpos-1;
}

void Creature::up(void)
{
    m_ypos = m_ypos-1;
}

void Creature::down(void)
{
    m_ypos = m_ypos+1;
}

void Creature::setX(int x)
{
    m_xpos = x;
}

void Creature::setY(int y)
{
    m_ypos = y;
}

int Creature::getX(void)
{
    return m_xpos;
}

int Creature::getY(void)
{
    return m_ypos;
}

===================================

//Hero.cpp

#include "Creature.h"
#include "Hero.h"

Hero::Hero(int lives) : Creature(m_name, m_xpos, m_ypos)
{
    m_lives = lives;
}

void Hero::Display(void)
{
    Creature::Display();
    cout << "Lives: " << m_lives << endl;
    cout << "Score: " << m_score << endl;
}

void Hero::setScore(void)
{
    m_score = 0;
}

===================================

//Monster.cpp

#include "Creature.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Hero.h"

Monster::Monster() : Creature(m_name, m_xpos, m_ypos)
{
}

void Monster::chase(Hero hero)
{
    if(getX() < hero.getX())
    {
        right();
    }

    if(getX() > hero.getX())
    {
        left();
    }

    if(getX() < hero.getX())
    {
        down();
    }

    if(getX() >hero.getX())
    {
        up();
    }
}

bool Monster::eaten(Hero hero)
{

    if((getX() == hero.getX())&&(getX() == hero.getX()))
    {
        return true;
    }
}


===================================
```

The problem lay in `Hero::Hero(int lives) : Creature(m_name, m_xpos, m_ypos)` and the equivilant with the Monster.cpp file.

Changing them to `Hero::Hero(int lives) : Creature("", 0,0)` fixed the memory problem.

Thanks again to a wonderful community!

Hopefully, you'll never see this code again! (fingers crossed!)

Comment: `Hero::Hero(int lives) : Creature(m_name` I don't think m_name is initialized at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is with this line:

```
Hero::Hero(int lives) : Creature(m_name, m_xpos, m_ypos)
```

You cannot create the `Creature` sub-object by passing its own **uninitialized** data members to it. You need to pass some sort of valid values to the base-class constructor, like `Creature("", 0, 0)` for example.

The error is caused, somehow, by the attempt to copy an uninitialized `std::string` object.

Comment: I knew it would be something silly! Thank you so much, you've just fixed everything.